# Internal function int, decreases the size when converting from str to int in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, type-conversion, python-3.8

This is my code:

```
import trng

bitn: int = 2 ** (2 ** 3)

w: "function" = lambda q=1: q * (trng.randbelow(1001) / 1000)


def rn(x0: int = None):

    if (m := trng.randbelow(bitn)) <= 1:
        m: int = 2
    a, c = (trng.randbelow(m) for _ in range(2))
    if (c := trng.randbelow(m)) <= 1:
        c: int = 2
    if x0 == None:
        x0: int = trng.randbelow(m)
    xs: list = [x0]
    for k in range(1, bitn):
        x = (a * xs[k - 1] + c) % m
        if xs.count(x) > 1:
            break
        xs.append(x)

    xs: str = str(sum(xs))
    x = trng.choice(xs)

    del m, a, c
    del x0, xs, k

    return x


def sm():

    listbits = [rn() for _ in range(64)]
    listbits: str = "".join(listbits)
    listbits: int = int(listbits)

    return listbits

while True: print(sm())
```

But, when I run this, python returns a number less than 64 characters, which is what I'm doing in the above code in the sm () function, I'm not able to understand. I've tried using the int function, outside the function (in the while loop), converting on the same line as I convert the list to string with the join method and an empty string, can someone help me please?
Thanks for your time and attention!
I'm using Windows 10 1903 x86 and Python 3.8.3

Comment: can you post the code of `trng.randbelow()` method

Comment: def randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound):
    """Return a random int in the range [0, n)."""
    if exclusive_upper_bound <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Upper bound must be positive.")
    return _sysrand._randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound)
equal to secrets.randbelow! Thanks

Comment: I'm tested your it returning the integer with 64 digits

Comment: Now I understand, in reality, when the program generates random numbers it has the chance to generate the number 0, and with the chance of it being the first number, assuming that the program generated "1238977341876486231712", when converting to int, it remains 1238977341876486231712, but when it generates for example "0001231239120303910091", when it converts to integer, python recognizes 0001231239120303910091 as 1231239120303910091, because the zero to the left makes no difference, it decreases the size of the number.